# Does the --module-path command set the modulepath temporarily?

Tags: java, module, java-module, module-path

I have noticed that once I use the `--module-path` command, I have to use it again when compiling the same java file.

Is this because the `--module-path` command appends to the module path temporarily ? If so, is there a way to set the `--module-path` permanently?

Comment: The value of `--module-path` is scoped to the invocation of the tool (e.g. `javac`) or application (e.g. `java`) you're running.

Comment: Does this mean that once javac/java is exited, the value of --module-path held is not remembered?

Comment: Yes, that means the value is lost when the process exits and the memory is released. Same as all the other command line options. However, you could put the value in a file and use `@filename` on the command line. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9).